Updating cms_page_view but not cms_index_index htmlClass
Trying to update all cms_page_view pages except for cms_index_index layouts.
E.g. on Magento_Theme/page_layout/cms_page_view.xml
<referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns bluey" />
But I want to remove it on any cms_index_index page. e.g. Magento/layout/cms_index_index.xml
<referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns" />
However the div will display class='columns bluey' on both cms/index page. So it seems like cms_index_index is loaded first and then cms_page_view is loaded second which overrides the initial changes.
Is there anyway to priorities cms_index_index over cms_page_view? Or is there a way to set the htmlClass for all cms pages except for index?
Thanks.
